# Open txt file in notepad using extension wild card using FSO

Tags: excel, vba

I would like write a excel macro to open a text file in notepad with wildcard as "*.txt" using FSO Object. I need to avoid shell command as it will be blocked in my workplace.

I tried the below code but it has specific file name and also using shell command.

```
Sub M08_OpenTXTFiles()
Dim filename1 As String
filename1 = "C:\L2Q\L2Q-W\SOURCE\TXT\u30033.txt"
Shell ("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" & " " & filename1), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

I need a macro to open a text file whose name is not known but only the extension is known as "*.txt" in a specific folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub txtopen()
ChDir "F:\Documenti" ' <<< change it
fopen = Application.GetOpenFilename("TXT files (*.txt), *.txt")
If fopen <> False Then
    Shell ("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" & " " & fopen), vbNormalFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is opening a file dialog to select the file. I have a pre-defined folder path and the text file in that folder must open.

Comment: As @Siraj said that `Shell` has to be avoided, maybe `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=fopen, NewWindow:=True` is a solution.